# Convert datetime string to valid date value and valid time value

Tags: vba, validation, excel, datetime

This code is returning as an invalid date for conversion:

> 'Wednesday, September 10, 2014 6:53 AM'

The VBA `IsDate` function is used to check if an expression is a `Date` or the expression can be converted to a valid `Date` or `Time`. The function returns `true` or `false`.

How can I get the date to be valid?

```
'-----------------------------------------

Dim x As Integer

x = ActiveCell.Row

'-----------------------------------------

Dim vDate As Variant

vDate = "Wednesday, September 10, 2014 6:53 AM"

MsgBox vDate

MsgBox IsDate(vDate) 'retuns false

'-----------------------------------------

Dim fDAT As String

fDAT = Left(vDate, Len(vDate) - 7)

MsgBox fDAT

MsgBox IsDate(fDAT) 'retuns false

'-----------------------------------------

''ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value = fDAT
```

Comment: Please note:  this is an rss pubdate format that I am trying to put into an 
Excel cell to be able to sort by date format DAY-MONTH-TIME

Comment: Remove the day and the following comma and space.

Comment: how would it work as the weekday name is not a fixed finite character count?  How would also combine both trims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would change:

```
fDAT = Left(vDate, Len(vDate) - 7)
```

To:

```
fDAT = Mid(vDate, InStr(vDate, ",") + 2)
```

Comment: wow, the change from the left to the mid WORKED!!! it returned back a true date value.

Comment: @LiterateAspects please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved with switching from left to mid with the fDAT - as provided by Scott Craner - thank you, wow!  what an excellent community- how do I now close this request?  THANK YOU SCOTT

Comment: @LiterateAspects you choose one of these as answer by clicking on the green check mark by the answer you choose.  That will not keep others from submitting more answers but it will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "Wednesday, " and try something like:

```
vDate = Format(vDate, "M/D/YYYY H:MM:SS AM/PM")
xDate = IsDate(vDate)
```

Comment: how can I get rid of the Wednesday, as that is the value in the cell.  Both the weekday names and the month names are not fixed finite character counts, so how could I select them by trim to remove?  oh and a big thank you, as I have been trying since early this morning San Francisco time to solve this.

Comment: how could this work as the format is not "M/D/YYYY H:MM:SS AM/PM"

Comment: that is what I am hoping to be able to do, to convert the rss pubdate into a string that I can sort on in Excel , oh and thank you!

Comment: Basically by getting rid of the "Wednesday ," excel will take it as a date, I just added it just to restate it. If the only way to eliminate the word is in the code, then I would use the functions Right() and Left() but first you need to know the length of the word.. ie Monday Tuesday... etc for that use conditionals like if Left(vDate,3) = "Mon" then length = 7

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved with switching from left to mid with the fDAT - as provided by Scott Craner - thank you, wow!  what an excellent community- how do I now close this request?

Comment: Great, you should click on the check mark next to Scott's answer.

Comment: ok, I did that, thank you... will this now show this as a successfully resolved IN RECORD TIME issue?

Answer (score 0):

to get also the correctness you can use something like that:

```
Sub blabla()
  Dim vDate As Variant, xDate As Boolean
  vDate = "Wednesday, September 10, 2014 6:53 AM"
  xDate = IsDate(vDate) Or (IsDate(Mid(vDate, InStr(vDate, ",") + 1)) And Left(vDate, InStr(vDate, ",") - 1) = Format(Mid(vDate, InStr(vDate, ",") + 1), "dddd"))
End Sub
```

this would also be false if it is not the correct weekday ;)

To get a usable value you could use something like:

```
If Not IsDate(vDate) And IsDate(Mid(vDate, InStr(vDate, ",") + 1)) Then vDate = Mid(vDate, InStr(vDate, ",") + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved with switching from left to mid with the fDAT - as provided by Scott Craner - thank you, wow!  what an excellent community- how do I now close this request?

Comment: Quote: *Click on the green check mark by the answer.* (from the answer you want to accept) ;)